# How do I make RxJava call onErrorReturn() and still execute onError()

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

When I call the Retrofit method `GetTodoRepository.fetchTodo()` from `MainViewModel` and call ends in a failure or any non-success result, I would like to let RxJava to both do `onErrorReturn()` and `onError()` so I can return a cached object in that case, but still notify `MainViewModel` that an error happend, so I can show error-related UI views. How do I archive this?

The current code shows how I intended to handle it.

**MainViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel

    public LiveData<String> getTodo() {
    getTodoRepository.fetchTodo().subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            showProgressAnim.setValue(false);
            todo.setValue(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            showProgressAnim.setValue(false);
            errorMsg.setValue(e.getMessage());
        }
     });
        return todo;
    }
}
```

**GetTodoRepository**

```
public class GetTodoRepository {

    public Single<String> fetchTodo() {
        return retrofit.create(TodoApi.class)
            .getTodo()
            .doOnSuccess(s -> cacheManager.saveTodo(s))
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> cacheManager.getTodo())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `onSuccess` and `onError` in the ViewModel at the same time? If so, that isn't possible. `onSuccess` and `onError` are terminal events and are mutually exclusive. You can treat the error as a different success state and pass it to the `onSuccess`. You can return an object which will hold the `String` you returned from the repository and a flag that denotes if it is from cache or not. So that you will always get a success callback even if API fails. In the onSuccess, you will be able to check it by doing something like `result.isFromCache()`

Comment: @SarathKn Yes I'm calling both. I did that with plain Java listeners before where you could call `listener.onSuccess(String msg)` and `listener.onError(String msg)` in any order or way one would in case of failed `GET` requests. How would I return a RxJava flag indicating that the returned value `isFromCache()`?

Comment: You can even use the approach suggested by @akarnokd. I'll add an answer with both the approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have both signal types with a `Single` but you can turn `fetchTodo()` into `Observable` and emit the cached item and the error together:

```
fetchTodo()
.toObservable()
.onErrorResumeNext(error -> 
     Observable.just(cached)
     .concatWith(Observable.error(error))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First approach which I mentioned in the comment is as follows

create a holder class for the result

```
     class ToDoResult {

            boolean isCached;
            String todo;
            Throwable error; // this will be set only in case of error

            public ToDoResult(String todo, boolean isCached) {
                this.isCached = isCached;
                this.todo = todo;
            }

            public void setError(Throwable error) {
                this.error = error;
            }
        }
```

Then make your fetchTodo() return `Single<ToDoResult>` instead of `Single<String>`  as follows

```
        public class GetTodoRepository {

            public Single<ToDoResult> fetchTodo() {
                return retrofit.create(TodoApi.class)
                    .getTodo()
                    .doOnSuccess(s -> cacheManager.saveTodo(s))
                    .map(todo -> new ToDoResult(todo,false))
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                        ToDoResult toDoResult = new ToDoResult(cacheManager.getTodo(), true);
                        toDoResult.setError(throwable);
                        return toDoResult;
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
            }
        }
```

And in you ViewModel

```
     getTodoRepository.fetchTodo().subscribe(new SingleObserver<ToDoResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ToDoResult toDoResult) {
                    showProgressAnim.setValue(false);
                    if (toDoResult.error != null) {
                        errorMsg.setValue(toDoResult.error.getMessage());
                    } else {
                        todo.setValue(toDoResult.todo);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    showProgressAnim.setValue(false);
                    errorMsg.setValue(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

In this approach, your `onError` will never get called since we are converting the error to a success signal always.

Second approach is as per @akarnokd mentioned in the previous answer to use an Observable and trigger the `onNext` and `onError` back to back.

```
 public class GetTodoRepository {

    public Observable<String> fetchTodo() {
        return  retrofit.create(TodoApi.class)
                        .getTodo()
                        .doOnSuccess(s -> cacheManager.saveTodo(s))
                        .toObservable()
                        .onErrorResumeNext(error ->
                                Observable.just(cached)
                                        .concatWith(Observable.error(error))
                        )
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

}
```

And change your view model like this

```
   getTodoRepository.fetchTodo().subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String s) {
             // this will be triggered with the todo item (cached in case of error)
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
           // this will be triggered followed by onNext in case of error
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second approach and the result was what I wanted